# how to edit hostname file using fabric

Tags: python, fabric

I have change my hosts file,so how to change hostname.my system is ubuntu.
eg my hosts file:

```
192.168.0.100 host1.mydomain.com
192.168.0.101 host2.mydomain.com
```

I wanna the hostname file under /etc/hostname of host1 to host1.mydomain.com,the hostname file of host2 to host2.mydomain.com

how to do that using fabric?
I have to ssh every host and edit the hostname file,does fabric can do this?

I didn't mean to use `hostname` command but to edit the /etc/hostname file.
I mean how to use fabric to do that:
such as:

```
def update_hostname():
  get("/etc/hosts","hosts")
  hosts_content = file("hosts")
  **hostname = ·get the hostname corespond to ip·**
  get("/etc/hostname","hostname")
  update `hostname file`
  put("hostname","/etc/hostname")
```

how get the ip? because fabric do the job on every host, and the hostname is correspond to each host. I need to know the which host the job is working and then get the ip back,then get the hostname correspond the the ip,and final update the hostname file.
[image]

Comment: Your question is probably more specific to the OS as mentioned below and not any scripting/programming, consider creating an account on http://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead for these types of questions.
Unless you have a codebase to post here the bet is quite high you're looking for a sysadmin related issue and not a code issue :)

Comment: mine is obviously not specific to os, maybe I didn't make my problem clear.mine is ubuntu,I want to change the hostname using fabric,the `hostname` command will be reset after reboot.

Comment: Then: echo "your new hostname" > /etc/hostname

Answer (score 1):

Fabric is just a SSH wrapper, so what you're looking at is LINUX specific, not frabric or python specific.

```
from fabric.api import run
run('hostname your-new-name')
run('echo your-new-hostname > /etc/hostname')
```

And just do a run(..edit..) according to your linux dist?

Or just do:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
hosts = open('/etc/networking/hosts', 'rb')
for hostline in hosts.readlines():
    ip, name = hostline.split(' ')
    command = ['ssh', '-t', 'root@' + host.strip('\r\n ,;), ' ', "echo " + name.strip('\r\n ,;) + " > /etc/hostname",]
    stdout, stderr = Popen(command, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE).communicate()
hosts.close()
```

**Note:** /etc/networking/hosts might be placed somewhere else for you.
The important part here is that you loop through the /hosts file, and ssh to each machine echoing the given hostname to that machine.

Comment: your method only apply for the moment,the hostname will reset after reboot.

Comment: Correct but i was mainly reffering to the fact that your question is first of all missguided, it's not a programming question per se, it's a administrative command that you're missing out on.
Secondly take your time to check your question for structural errors cause there are a few which makes it hard to understand what you're looking for. But now when i read your question again (after you've updated) and for the 5:th time yes this is possible via fabric. **You would still need to SSH to each machine (via fabric)**

Comment: Consider my last change (Update done in Python via SSH to the remote host)

Comment: torxed,sorry to make you missguied.actually I don't know how to get the hostname. In my situation,I want to update the hostname file after updating hosts file.

Comment: Added yet another fix for you. I gave you the basics, now i've given you the complete answer :) Try imagining what you could do with the given examples and not what they do..

Comment: torxed,thx you do that using subprocess,it seemd env.host_string in fabric is what I'm finding.

Comment: Don't mix fabric and what i'm trying to help you with unless you know what you're doing. In my example above i don't use fabric at all to manage anything. I manually read the local **hosts** (plural) which you define some how. Then i SSH to those hosts (defined in /hosts) and change their hostname respectivly.

env.host_string is __only__ your local hostname, and according to your question i'm not sure what you would need it for.

Comment: env.host_string in fabric mean the current host in every iteration.:-)

Comment: Yes but you have posted 0 rows of code basically so for all intense and purposes env.host_string is your local hostname.

Please post your entire codebase. What i'm trying to say is that, it's hard to guess that you've actually iterated through your hosts (how have you've done this?), and that your env.host_string is in an actual iteration? because.. i can't see that anywhere.

Comment: I have pasted my code,it still have some errors,I'm fixing it.

Comment: I give up, but it's good that you finally posted some code because this is.. a code.. community :P And for future reference, post your code and not a screenshot of it (which makes it possible for future editing)

Comment: I know,but I edit my code remotely via putty,I can't copy the code,so I just take a screenshot.thx torxed.

Comment: And no that's not edited code via putty that's Sublime Text 2 or __Notepad++__ (my guess is on the later) you've taken a screenshot of.
Secondly, if that's the case consider using WinSCP or if you're proper you can use scp or mount a scp directory and edit locally and have automated pushes to your remote host. But guessing you're on windows so WinSCP is a great application.

Answer (score 1):

```
def hostname():

   '''
   function to change the hostname of the ubuntu server
   '''

   server_hostname = prompt ("The Hostname for the server is :")

   sed ("/etc/hostname", before='current hostname', after='%s' % (server_hostname), use_sudo=True,backup='')

   sudo ("init 6")
```

This will change the hostname according to your choice.

Answer (score 0):

in your fabric script you'll need to...

- ssh into the machine as a user permitted to edit the hosts file ( via permissions or groups ).  if you need to `sudo` into a user, search StackOverflow for issues regarding sudo and Fabric -- you'll need to tweak your fabfile to not prompt for a password.
- fabric can have an awkward way to deal with reading/writing/opening files.  you'll may be best off by `cd` into the right directory.  something like...

  with cd('/etc/')
      run('echo new_hostname hostname')

Comment: I don't know how to get the ip of the current job of a fabric process.