# how to add an element in json file which is located on remote machine

Tags: python, json, bash, shell, jq

I have a file `services.json` which is located on remote machine,

```
[
  {
    "kind": "SpecialService",
    "type": "attribute",
    "spec": {
      "addresses": [
        "172.21.3.196:6379"
      ]
    },
    "apiVersion": "rbac.newDevops.com/v1",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "redis",
      "description": "autogenerated by superagent.py script"
    }
  },
]
```

Now, the task is to append the above file with the following element in json.

```
{
            "kind": "PilotService",
            "apiVersion": "rbac.newDevops.com/v1",
            "type": "attribute-based",
            "metadata": {
                "name": "apache",
                "description": "apache service as a process"
            },
            "spec": {
                "addresses": [
                    "172.22.0.7/24:80"
                ]
            }
}
```

Once we add the content into the json file we need to close the array of the existing json. (The file content starts with an array.)

I tried using python to perform ssh to the remote machine but I'm failing in editing json on remote machine using `jq` or with `open` of python

Any guidance on this like how do we edit json files on remote machine?

Comment: If you are allowed to do this, you could take a local copy of the remote file, edit it, send it back.  Or create a python script on the remote system that performs the edit.  But you will not be able to open a remote file directly in your local python script, unless of course if you NFS mount the remote file system (or similar).

Comment: can't i do ssh using paramiko and then use some exec_command of bash or jq to achieve it.

Comment: Sure if you have ssh access, you could run `echo "new content" >>json_file` or something similar.

Comment: i tried this, it's a json object & hence normal redirection is not helping much in retaining the valid json.

Comment: ah yes, or course.  Then a small script is required.  Create a new file that has a copy of the original file minus the last line (]), then >> the new content, then >> ] to close the JSON.

Comment: it looks like, there's something called as jq utility which can help us in doing it in a better way editing of json

Comment: ok, I do not know jq, hopefully someone else will.

Comment: @frpfarhan, login to the remote host via SSH, then, edit your file

Comment: i can login using paramiko and python, but then editing it at the remote place using jq is giving me trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the first file is array.json and the second object.json, then ignoring the various ssh/rsync/sponge options, the basic jq invocation would be along the lines:

```
jq —-argfile object object.json ‘. + [$object]’ array.json
```

There are several quite reasonable alternatives, depending on your version of jq.

Let's suppose that the object to be added is not conveniently available as a FILE or STDIN; presumably it can at least be made available as a shell variable.  In that case you could tweak the above incantation along the following lines:

```
jq —-argjson object "$object" ‘. + [$object]’ array.json
```

Please consult the [jq manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) for further variations.

As for the remote/local stuff, assuming jq is available locally, maybe you'd be best off using rsync to fetch the remote file to local, perform the update, and then rsync back to remote.  There are countless variations, but I'd put everything in a script so that you can easily add refinements to deal with unexpected situations, etc.

Comment: array.json is a file on the remote machine, however object.json is not a file its just a data which we have and we are on local machine.

Comment: @frpfarhan - See updated answer.   Are you familiar with rsync?

Answer (score 2):

Using bash and process substitution (`<(command)`):

```
$ jq -s '.' <(jq '.[]' file1) file2
[
  {
    "kind": "SpecialService",
    "type": "attribute",
    "spec": {
      "addresses": [
        "172.21.3.196:6379"
      ]
    },
    "apiVersion": "rbac.newDevops.com/v1",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "redis",
      "description": "autogenerated by superagent.py script"
    }
  },
  {
    "kind": "PilotService",
    "apiVersion": "rbac.newDevops.com/v1",
    "type": "attribute-based",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "apache",
      "description": "apache service as a process"
    },
    "spec": {
      "addresses": [
        "172.22.0.7/24:80"
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

You could use this as the substitution for `file1`: `<(ssh user@remote jq '.[]' file1)` you just need to setup ssh keys to omit password querying. There are plenty of guides on doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If you can figure out how to edit a file programmatically, doing it over SSH is not any more complicated, just two steps instead of one.

```
import json

newdata = {
    "kind": "PilotService",
    "apiVersion": "rbac.newDevops.com/v1",
    "type": "attribute-based",
    "metadata": {
            "name": "apache",
            "description": "apache service as a process"
        },
    "spec": {
            "addresses": [
                "172.22.0.7/24:80"
            ]
    }

with open('services.json') as jdata:
    data = json.load(jdata)
data.append(newdata)
with open('services.json', 'w') as writable:
    writable.write(json.dump(data))
```

If you can save this script on the remote host, all you need is

```
ssh remote python script.py
```

but you might want to look into using Fabric or Paramiko to encapsulate the entire process.

If the file is big, you might want to avoid the open file for reading, read into memory, close, open for writing, write pattern, but that's usually the most straightforward way to do it. (You can open for reading and writing, and rewind when you are done reading, but that doesn't really help against race conditions if you might have several processes writing to the same file.)

Comment: we can't save anything on remote machine, hence was wondering if we can do it just by login into remote and using some exec_command

Comment: Something like this then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14711861/how-to-edit-hostname-file-using-fabric

Answer (score 0):

So finally by trying multiple answers I thought to post the actual solution to the problem.

file1.json:

```
{
                "kind": "PilotService",
                "apiVersion": "rbac.newDevops.com/v1",
                "type": "attribute-based",
                "metadata": {
                    "name": "apache",
                    "description": "apache service as a process"
                },
                "spec": {
                    "addresses": [
                        "172.22.0.7/24:80"
                    ]
                }
}
```

file2.json:

```
[
  {
    "kind": "SpecialService",
    "type": "attribute",
    "spec": {
      "addresses": [
        "172.21.3.196:6379"
      ]
    },
    "apiVersion": "rbac.newDevops.com/v1",
    "metadata": {
      "name": "redis",
      "description": "autogenerated by superagent.py script"
    }
  },
]
```

on the shell terminal:

```
object=`cat file2.json`

jq --argjson object "$object" ". + [$object]" file1.json > beta.json
```